# how to generate a random number in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

newbie in AnyLogic here  ,

I am having a difficulty in dealing with this environment ,  am trying to know how i can generate a random number between 0.5 and 0.8 of type double and put it in a parameter  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `uniform(a,b)` function. a is the minimum, b is is the maximum. Say your parameter is called `myParameter`, you can set its value to uniform random number at any place in the simulation by `myParameter=uniform (0.5, 0.8)`

Comment: Thank you , do i put the " myParameter=uniform (0.5, 0.8) " in the default value of the parameter  ?

Comment: If you are not going to change the value during the simulation, then put this code on Main->on startup section.